# How to create new escape sequence?

Tags: c, escaping, printf

Is it possible to make a whole `printf()` string be converted  `toupper()` or `tolower()` automatically via an escape sequence? How to do that?

Escape sequence are those that having "\" back slash when printing. tolower() enables you to convert uppercase letter to lowercase. toupper() enables you to convert lowercase letter into uppercase. But is it possible to make/add an escape sequence that also have the same function of tolower() and toupper(). For example, I'm going to create new escape sequence "\u" and "\l". \u as the `toupper()` and it will be used like this.

```
printf("\u hello world");
```

Output:

```
HELLO WORLD
```

The string next to the escape sequence will be converted to uppercase letters. It is also the same with the `\l` as `tolower()`.
How to do that? Please help me.

Comment: use [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) to convert string and print normally

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a whole `printf()` string be converted  `toupper()` or `tolower()` automatically via an escape sequence?

No, you cannot do that.

The escape sequences are defined by the language. You can't add to them.

Comment: for some implementations, you can extend printf  formats. eg. [glibc extending printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html)

Comment: @amdixon, true. This might be what the OP needs to use but they expressed it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

- You can make new function as `Printf_new()` and in that you can parse
- its argument and get `\i` or `\u` and depending upon that
- call
  `toupper()` and `tolower()` convert your string and then again
- call
  original `printf()`

Comment: Note: you can't use `\i` and `\u` because you can't add backslash escape sequences. You could use `%I` and `%U` or something like that.

Comment: @immibis To add to your comment "C11 6.11.4 Character escape sequences" "Lowercase letters as escape sequences are reserved for future standardization. Other characters may be used in extensions."

Answer (score 0):

No. This isn't in any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own print function with your own inbuilt escape sequences. Something like this:

```
printf_reimagined(const char * format, ... )
{
  const char * formatted;
  for(int i = 0; format[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if(format[i] == '//'
    {
      switch(format[i+])
      {
        case 'u':
          // Convert to upper case
          ... do formatting
          break;
        case 'l':
          // Convert to lower case
          ... do formatting
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  printf(formatted, ...);
}
```

You would then use `\\u` or `\\l` for your escape sequences.
Sorting out any other arguments would need to be done here too mind.

I did something similar recently but I did have to make \ become \\